# Using node.js to create a MongoDB connection at runtime

Tags: node.js

My node.js application has one MongoDB (db1) which has user details. Each user has different database (MongoDB). So I maintain all the database information in db1.

Here my question is based on user: I need to open user database connection at runtime and perform some operation in user database.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My app.js is:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"); 
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/testA');
var conn2 = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/testB');

var modelConfig = require('./api/model/action.model');

modelConfig.dynamicModel(conn, function (model) {
    model.create({name: 'testA', description: 'description A'}, function (err, data) {
        console.log("data: " + data);
        console.log("err: " + err);
    });
});

modelConfig.dynamicModel(conn2, function (model) {
    model.create({name: 'testB', description: 'description B'}, function (err, data) {
        console.log("data: " + data);
        console.log("err: " + err);
    });
});
```

My model file look like below:

```
'use strict';
var restful = require("node-restful");
var mongoose = restful.mongoose;
var modelConfig = require('../schema/action.schema');
var actionSchema = new mongoose.Schema(modelConfig.schema);

module.exports.dynamicModel = function(con,cb){
    var action = con.model(modelConfig.title, actionSchema);
    cb(action);
};
```

My schema file look like bellow.

```
'use strict';    
var restful = require("node-restful");
var mongoose = restful.mongoose;

module.exports = {
    title: "action",   //mongo db collection name
    schema: {
        name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true},
        description: { type: String, required: false} 
    }
}
```

Install node-restful, mongoose and mongodb package and node app.

It will save the recodes in testA and testB database.